# Combining bash and CMD in Linux under Windows 10

Tags: bash, cmd, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the Linux subsystem under Windows 10.

If I have, for example, a PowerPoint file called `x.pptx`, I can request the Linux bash shell to request Windows to open the file with the default application. The following command will do the trick:

```
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C start x.pptx
```

But if the file name contains a space (for example, `x y.pptx`) I can't get it to work. I think I have tried every possible combination of single quotes, double quotes and backslashes.

Is what I want to do even possible?

**EDIT**

Here are my attempts:

Using `x\ y.pptx` or `"x y.pptx"` or `'x y.pptx'` or `\"x y.pptx\"` simply causes the CMD window to open.

Using `'"x y.pptx"'` causes Windows to say that it cannot find `y.pptx\` (the missing x and the backslash are not typos).

Using `'\"x y.pptx\"'` causes Windows to say that it cannot find `y.pptx\\\` (sic).

Comment: have you tried with absolute path? is `x y...`in current working directory? start has also /D option to specify directory

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, yes I have tried with the absolute path. Yes, `x y.pptx` is in the current working directory. Adding the /D option doesn't seem to help.

Comment: trying various `start` commands in cmd shows the same result using title seems to be a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems the reason comes from `start` command:

from `start /?`, it seems the first quoted string is used as title, giving a title seems to be a workaround

```
start "title" "x y.pptx"
```

and launching from bash

```
/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C start '"title"' 'x y.pptx'
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I just get a CMD window with a title of "x y.pptx". (The `start "title" "x y.pptx"` works nicely when executed directly in CMD, but I can't get it to work from bash.)

Comment: because bash quoting, updating answer

Comment: Nahuel, your edit doesn't work, but this does:  `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C  start '"title"' 'x y.pptx'`.